# Localized Video Resources in HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: http-live-streaming

I'm trying to create a VOD using HTTP Live Streaming technology. Everything works fine so far **except delivering localized video resources**.

I want to show a (powerpoint) presentation (as video) via HTTP Live Streaming. The **slides are available in English and German**. Their is also an audio part available in English and German.

For testing purposes I've embedded this in a simple web page and tried to view it on my iPhone and this works, **except switching (or show by default) the correct language of video**. I'm only able to switch the audio resource to German. (German as my default iPhone language is also not detected.)

I've read almost the whole draft on HTTP Live Streaming but their is no information about that if it should work and I'm doing something wrong or if this shouldn't work. In paragraph [3.4.10 and 3.4.10.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-11#section-3.4.10) there is something written about multiple groups and it seems that i can apply the LANGUAGE key to the VIDEO resource. (Usually it should also be possible to provide multiple video streams for different camera angles for instance, so why not for different languages)

So now here is my `*.m3u8` master playlist file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio-all",LANGUAGE="en",NAME="English",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="en/audio/prog_index.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio-all",LANGUAGE="de",NAME="German",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="de/audio/prog_index.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=VIDEO,GROUP-ID="video-low",LANGUAGE="en",NAME="English",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="en/low/prog_index.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=VIDEO,GROUP-ID="video-low",LANGUAGE="de",NAME="German",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="de/low/prog_index.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=VIDEO,GROUP-ID="video-medium",LANGUAGE="en",NAME="English",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="en/medium/prog_index.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=VIDEO,GROUP-ID="video-medium",LANGUAGE="de",NAME="German",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="de/medium/prog_index.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=VIDEO,GROUP-ID="video-high",LANGUAGE="en",NAME="English",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="en/high/prog_index.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=VIDEO,GROUP-ID="video-high",LANGUAGE="de",NAME="German",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="de/high/prog_index.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=VIDEO,GROUP-ID="video-720p",LANGUAGE="en",NAME="English",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="en/720p/prog_index.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=VIDEO,GROUP-ID="video-720p",LANGUAGE="de",NAME="German",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="de/720p/prog_index.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=VIDEO,GROUP-ID="video-1080p",LANGUAGE="en",NAME="English",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="en/1080p/prog_index.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=VIDEO,GROUP-ID="video-1080p",LANGUAGE="de",NAME="German",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="de/1080p/prog_index.m3u8"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=128000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio-all"
de/audio/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=660000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.42e015",AUDIO="audio-all",VIDEO="video-low"
de/low/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=800000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.42e01e",AUDIO="audio-all",VIDEO="video-medium"
de/medium/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1070000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.4d401f",AUDIO="audio-all",VIDEO="video-high"
de/high/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1728000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.4d401f",AUDIO="audio-all",VIDEO="video-720p"
de/720p/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=3300000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.4d4029",AUDIO="audio-all",VIDEO="video-1080p"
de/1080p/prog_index.m3u8
```

According to the draft and the docs of Apple it should be possible to provide multiple video streams.

I also removed the LANGUAGE keys and tried to  do it as in [this example from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2288/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012238-CH1-SOURCECODE13). But i'm also not able to choose different video streams.

1. What am i doing wrong?
2. Is it possible to provide multiple streams related to the language? (As possible with AUDIO and SUBTITLE)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're expected to use different top level playlist if you want alternate video files (beyond bandwidth and quality settings).

Comment: No. It's possible to provide different video streams for different camera angles as described in the example from Apple and according to the specification. But you can't choose them on iOS or in Quicktime on Mac. It seems like a bug for me.